# Структура хранения данных в базе mysql

Tags: mysql, связывание-данных, php, база-данных, sql

Знатоки. Внимание вопрос! ЯП: php, БД: mysql.

Передо мной стоит задача по созданию некого аналога афиши. Создать саму афишу с каталогом не составило большого труда. Вопрос встал в прикреплении к афише места/даты/времени.

**Место**: вписанное пользователем или выбранное из уже имеющихся (мест) т.е id. (Строка или число). К месту может быть привязано много дат.

**Дата**: одна дата, две даты, n дат, интервал дат. К дате может быть привязано несколько "времён"

**Время**: по аналогии с датой, 10:20 или 10:20,11:25 или 10:20 - 12:20

Проблема заключается в том как хранить эти данные в базе данных, записей будет много и нужно будет подготовить максимально удобную платформу для выборки по месту/дате/времени.

Рассматривались несколько вариантов: создать три таблицы схематично:
**места**: *id, content, content_type* 
   *content_type* сообщает нам тип содержимого поля *content*.
Или же иначе эта таблица может выглядеть так *id, place, place_id* 
   одно из полей будет всегда пустым. Связь к датам один ко многим.

**даты**: *id, date1, date2* 
   одна из дат пуста, или обе заполнены значит интервал. Связь к времени один ко многим.

**время**: *id, time1, time2*
   если оба заполнены то интервал или одно.

Какие еще есть варианты решения поставленной задачи.

Comment: По вашей схеме у тфблицы Места может быть много дат, но у таблицы Даты не наблюдается поле (типа PlaceId) для связывания с таблицей Места. Такая же ситуация и с таблицей Время. Или я чего-то не понял)

Comment: Вы правильно все поняли. Я опустил эти вещи в вопросе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У каждой записи афиша/место/дата/время - по таблице в БД.

У каждой записи - уникальный ИД в их таблице.

Таблица типа links с полями: parent_id, child_id, parent_type, child_type.

Такая конструкция позволяет строить любые типы связей и в любом количестве.
Выборка двумя join'ами.

Answer (score 0):

в больших субд где очень важны даты/время (напр. подсчет каких-то характеристик производительности чего-то там за определенное время) используют отдельные таблицы для хранения даты и времени. к тому же они обычно хранятся еще и в "разобраном" виде, - т.е разделены на отдельные поля: год, месяц, день, часы, минуты, секунды...

напр:

```
// собственно ваши "афиши"
item_def : id, name, description

// даты событий задаются отдельно
// если событие "одноразовое" то end может быть null, или соответствовать старту
date_def : id, start, end

// по аналогии с датами
time_def: id, start, end

// собственно описание времени событий
occurences: id, item_id, date_id, time_id
```

p.s. в случае разбиения даты и времени на составляющие структура таблиц date_def и time_def немного усложнится, хотя их можно будет разбить на составляющие:

```
time_def: id, hour_id, minute_id , second_id (с таблиц hours_def, minutes_def, seconds_def)
date_def: id, year_id, month_id, day_id
```

структура получается немного перегруженная, но для некоторых составляющих таблицы делать необязательно. сомневаюсь что будет необходимость задавать событие которое будет происходить в определенную даты на протяжении 5 лет (хотя всякое бывает).

возможно для того чтоб упростить использование придется делать view с join'ами 2-3 таблиц